# Displaying Toast message in PostExecute method of an AsyncTask Android App

Tags: java, android, listview, android-asynctask

Ok, so I have an `AsyncTask` that is adding items to a `ListView`. On PreExecute, I am displaying a message "Starting" and on PostExecute I am displaying "Done". The "Starting" message is displayed but for some reason, when the listing is done, the "Done" message is NOT displayed. Does anyone have any ideas on why the message is not displaying in the PostExecute section of this Task? Thank you

Code:

```
class FillLocations extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {

    public FillLocations() {

    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Starting",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    // Decode image in background.
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        String result = "";
        InputStream isr = null;
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://myscript/"); // YOUR
                                                                                // PHP
                                                                                // SCRIPT
                                                                                // ADDRESS
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            isr = entity.getContent();
            // resultView.setText("connected");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }
        // convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(isr, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            isr.close();

            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error  converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // parse json data
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                final JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        try {

                            BitmapWorkerTask myTask = new BitmapWorkerTask(
                                    json.getInt("ID"), json);
                            myTask.execute();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                });

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

    }
}
```

Comment: because you didnt properly override onPostExecute so it does not call what you have

Comment: `onPostExecute()` no param to the method . ALso why use runOnUiThread in doinbackground. its supposed to be invoked on a back ground thread

Comment: @tyczj can you explain how I can fix this? Adding `@Override` gives an error

Comment: look at the documentation to see how to override it properly http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onPostExecute takes a parameter as shown [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29).

Personally, I would do something like this, to tell the user that something went wrong, in case some exception is thrown. I never liked letting errors go to nirvana.

```
protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
...
}
```

and

```
protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();

}
```

(Also, in the documentation, no `@Override` is used.)

Comment: This worked. I am having another problem now, when this onPostExecute message is displaying, the ListView items are still displaying...I was under the impression that onPostExecute happens only AFTER everything in doInBackground is done, is this correct?

Comment: The documentation indeed states that it will be called after doInBackground is done. After all, it will get the returned value of doInBackground passed as its parameter. It won't be called if the doInBackground is cancelled.

Comment: Hm, okay, for some reason "Done" is displayed before every item is added to my ListView (which is done in doInBackground)

Comment: Do you start your AsyncTask multiple times?

Comment: Nope, all I do isFillLocations myFill = new FillLocations(); then myFill.execute(); one time

Answer (score 0):

You need to appropriately implement onPostExecute

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void void){
      // Do what you want to do, for example, your toast:
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
}
```

`-Notes on General Practice-`

Your AsyncTask doesn't need a constructor, so you can remove

```
public FillLocations(){
}
```

And you should declare your class visibility (unless you want it set to the default visibility which is the package), so make it something like

```
private class FillLocations extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>{
    // Your Stuff
}
```

Comment: When I do this, I get the error `The method onPostExecute() of type MainActivity.FillLocations must override or implement a supertype method`

Comment: @user1282637 don't know how to help you past this based on your code. Might want to make the mentioned changes to your code, but it won't help with the mentioned error (I don't believe it will at least)